# Ionic App Issues After Relogin Except Ionic Button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a simple Ionic app (v5). Everything works when the user logs in for the first time. But once the user logs out, almost everything starts to have a problem.

- Cannot click on form elements to edit them
- Cannot click on hyperlinks, or normal buttons
- Ionic Menu is unclickable
- Ionic Tabs do not show the active tab anymore.

Everything is unclickable or exhibiting abnormal behavior, except Ionic Buttons which work perfectly still.

Unclickable Items are shown as:
[image]

[image]

But the ionic button works everywhere.

[image]

I can't seem to know if I am doing something wrong. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you checked the javascript console output? I'll bet there's a bunch of errors

Comment: Also posting your code would be good (the relevant parts) - and any errors from your console

Comment: There are no errors in the console. And I don't know what the issue is to know the relevant parts for it. I will try to create a Stackblitz/JSFiddle for this.